# “have someone V/Ving” in American English

Tags: american-english, causative-have

In American English, which verb form should be used in the following?

> He had the bouncers **throw**/**throwing** them out of the club.

> he had me **do**/**doing** all kinds of jobs for her.

Checking the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary and Longman Advanced American Dictionary, the latter lists both patterns. One might be tempted to conclude both patterns are possible in AmE. However, as the latter dictionary is adapted from the former, one cannot ignore the possibility that the editors failed to fully Americanize the dictionary. Fully American dictionaries such as the Merriam-Webster Advanced Learner's Dictionary only list the "have someone V" pattern.

Comment: Reminder: please keep your cool. Don't insult other people. Be nice. On the other hand, this is _not_ an easy question. The causative "have" is really anything but.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both patterns are possible in AmE, though they mean slightly different things and therefore aren’t completely exchangeable. Specifically, it mirrors the difference between the past and the past continuous tenses (or present and present continuous, etc., depending on what basic tense *have* has in your sentence).

It then becomes a question of whether the past or the past continuous is appropriate (or both).

- The bouncers threw them out (this is fine)
- The bouncers were throwing them out (there isn’t any context here indicating the progressive is appropriate, though there could be)

And the other:

- I did all kinds of jobs (fine)
- I was doing all kinds of jobs (also fine and puts a very slight emphasis on the fact that doing all those jobs took a while)

Here are some real examples:

- > And then the next day, she called something else in because she felt it wasn't good enough, and they **had the cops come and take** my son away. (Talk of the Nation, transcript via [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/))
- > She remains a spectacular talent, vivid in her interpretation of a song, not only vocally but in stage presence and in athletically powerful body language that **had the audience cheering** its lungs out. ([Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/lifestyle/2004/04/20/pop-music/0fb9d5d0-7ce2-4a2c-9a1a-78f583717e29/))
- > Pulled the guy off... and then a shorter one came in from the small office... next to the kitchen where he **had the bartender opening** the safe. (NYPD Blue, transcript via [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/))

For the first example, it’s not possible to use the continuous. In the second, the continuous just sounds better to me because it’s used for a long, drawn out action, though the other form is also acceptable. (Though the meaning of *had* here is slightly different, the same grammar applies.) In the third example, the continuous is required because opening the safe was happening at the same time as everything else, in the background.

Comment: ". . . had the audience cheering its lungs out" actually illustrates a different usage of "have" than the examples in the OP. The audience example is about the body language's effect on the audience, whereas the examples in the OP are about asking or ordering someone to do something. The two senses are kept distinct in the dictionary.

Comment: The context for the bouncer Ving is - "The Emperor's edict had the bouncers throwing the hockey fans out of the sports bars as soon as they got drunk.  That's why there was so much chaos in the streets last night."

Comment: @EllieK In that context, the continuous is appropriate because the bouncers were throwing people out all night.

Comment: The "have" in the audience example is recorded in major learner's dictionaries, American and British, as requiring Ving, not bare infinitive.